# Prove in axiomatic system S

Tags: logic, axioms

The question is to prove this in the axiomatic system S:

$$(\forall x)(\forall y)((A_x \rightarrow R_{xy})  \rightarrow \neg A_y)  \vdash  (\forall x)(R_{xx}  \rightarrow \neg A_x) $$

The problem is, I don't have any idea how to begin. The axioms about quantors can be used, in addition to the following axioms, but for this example I don't know with which axiom to start first:

1. $A\rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$
2. $(A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C))$
3. $(\lnot A\rightarrow \lnot B)\rightarrow (B\rightarrow A)$

Comment: Of course you need the quantification axioms... What inference rules do you have? only *modus ponens* or also *Generalization* ?

Comment: Both modus ponens and also generalization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

1) $(∀x)(∀y) \ ((Ax → Rxy) → ¬Ay)$ --- premise

2) $(Ax → Rxx) → ¬Ax$ --- from Ax: $\forall x \alpha \to \alpha[t/x]$ and 1) by *modus ponens* twice

3) $Rxx$ --- assumed [a]

4) $Rxx \to (Ax \to Rxx)$ --- Ax.1

5) $Ax \to Rxx$ --- from 3) and 4) by *mp*

6) $¬Ax$ --- from 5) and 2) by *mp*

7) $Rxx \to ¬Ax$ --- from 3) and 6) by *Deduction Th*

> 8) $\forall x \ (Rxx \to ¬Ax)$ --- from 7) by *Generalization*.

---

To be more "formal", we have to omit 1) and 3), and step 2) is:

2') $(∀x)(∀y) \ ((Ax → Rxy) → ¬Ay), Rxx \vdash (Ax → Rxx) → ¬Ax$

while step 4) is:

4') $\vdash Rxx \to (Ax \to Rxx)$

and so on :

5') $(∀x)(∀y) \ ((Ax → Rxy) → ¬Ay), Rxx \vdash Ax \to Rxx$

6') $(∀x)(∀y) \ ((Ax → Rxy) → ¬Ay), Rxx \vdash ¬Ax$

from which, by *Deduction Th* : if $\Gamma, \alpha \vdash \beta$, then $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$, where $\Gamma = \{ \ (∀x)(∀y) \ ((Ax → Rxy) → ¬Ay) \ \}$ :

> 7') $(∀x)(∀y) \ ((Ax → Rxy) → ¬Ay)  \vdash Rxx \to ¬Ax$

and finally:

> > $(∀x)(∀y) \ ((Ax → Rxy) → ¬Ay) \vdash (∀x) \ (Rxx \to ¬Ax)$.

Comment: Thanks, but where in your step 3) does the assumption Rxx come from?

Comment: @FerengiGodfried - it is an *assumption*, "discarded" with the *Deduction Th* in step 3).

Comment: So $$  ( A_x \rightarrow R_{xy})  \rightarrow \neg A_y)  \vdash (R_{xx}  \rightarrow \neg A_x) $$  becomes $$ (A_x \rightarrow R_{xy})  \rightarrow \neg A_y),  R_{xx}   \vdash \neg A_x $$ ? Right?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which syntax/basic rules you need to use, but generally it'll be something like this:

$$(\forall x)(\forall y)((A_x \rightarrow R_{xy}) \rightarrow \neg A_y)$$
$$(\forall x)((A_x \rightarrow R_{xx}) \rightarrow \neg A_x)$$
($\forall$ elimination)
$$(\forall x)(\neg (A_x \rightarrow R_{xx}) \vee \neg A_x)$$
(definition of $\rightarrow$ elimination, for some systems; if you don't have it, you should prove it from what you're given)
$$(\forall x)(\neg (\neg A_x \vee R_{xx}) \vee \neg A_x)$$
($\rightarrow$ elimination)
$$(\forall x)((A_x \wedge \neg R_{xx}) \vee \neg A_x)$$
(de morgan's)
$$(\forall x)(\neg R_{xx} \vee \neg A_x)$$
($\wedge$ elimination)
$$(\forall x)(R_{xx}  \rightarrow \neg A_x)$$
($\rightarrow$ introduction)